# Asp .NET Core use string in resource as image src path

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to put image urls in a single file but im unable to achieve this

on my resources i have a variable with the value which is the path for the image

```
~/img/ajax/loader-ellipsis.svg
```

and on my image i want to use the strong typed path

```
<img src="@Urls.Loader_Image" width="50" />
```

but it does not show the image

**EDIT**

I added a using in imports to access resources

```
@using myProject.Resources
```

and the resource file is called Urls, and the string Name is Loader_Image

Comment: What is `@Urls.Loader_Image`? How do you set it?

Comment: the resource file is called Urls, updated with more info

Comment: and what value in src after rendering?

Comment: `<img src="~/img/ajax/loader-ellipsis.svg" width="50">` this is what appears in browser but no image

Comment: You'll need to expand the `~` out using `@Url.Content(Urls.Loader_Image)`

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the path in your resource file "as is" because, when the Asp.Net rendering engine renders a page, it retrieves all the references resources and dynamically places then in their respective locations. For the engine to know that your variable is a path, it must see the root path notation at compile time in order for it to get the path exactly. What is being sent to the web browser is not what was generated at compile time but at runtime. Bring the root path notation behind your resource allocator in order for it to get your root path as follows

```
<img src="~ @Urls.Loader_Image" width="50" />
```

Then remove the server root notation from your resource file away. Note the space after the root notation in my example

Comment: this does not work, this is rendered `<img src="~ /img/ajax/loader-ellipsis.svg" width="50">` only the @Url.Content approach worked

Comment: Did you put the backward slash after the root notation?